# Why won't my animation render as a video?

Tags: rendering

I downloaded a template from youtube and used that. I only changed the text and I didn't mess with the resolution, settings, or anything else. I selected Animation under the render tab and let it go through the cycle and it took over night! Once it was finally completed, guess what? IT DID NOTHING! It gave me a black screen and then when I opened the downloads and played the video, it like a .5 second clip of a single picture. What's going on? Why won't it render like it is supposed to? Did I mess something up? The clip is only about 20 seconds long and I left the settings for render in Cycle Render. I really need this to work. PLEASE HELP!

Comment: Please post a screenshot of your render settings, including the **Output** tab.

Comment: It is unfortunate that you spent all of that time rendering without results. In order to help you we need to know more about your scene and specifically of your render settings. Without that is very hard to help you. Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question and add more information and screenshots.

Comment: Never ever render directly from 3D to a video format